# .htaccess RewriteRule to webserver without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to do a port-forwarding with .htaccess, like the following scenario:

```
https://example.com                => http://getcontent.from:8080
https://example.com/test           => http://getcontent.from:8080/test
https://example.com/favicon.ico    => http://getcontent.from:8080/favicon.ico
https://example.com/img/asdf.png   => http://getcontent.from:8080/img/asdf.png
```

But the url should always stay 'example.com'.

The primary target is to forward to a node-server on a different server because I have no https there.

Comment: So just to be clear https://example.com will redirect to http://getcontent.from:8080 but the URL in browser will show https://example.com?

Comment: @error2007s yeah exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example #2 from [brontobytes](https://www.brontobytes.com/knowledgebase/202/htaccess-URL-Masking-Examples.html), just change the port as well.